# How to truncate the values of a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a two-dimensional numpy array(uint16), how can I truncate all values above a certain barrier(say 255) to that barrier? The other values must stay the same. Using a nested loop seems to be ineffecient and clumsy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.array([[100, 200], [300, 400]],np.uint16)
my_array[my_array > 255] = 255
```

the output will be

```
array([[100, 200],
       [255, 255]], dtype=uint16)
```

Answer (score 21):

actually there is a specific method for this, 'clip':

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.array([[100, 200], [300, 400]],np.uint16)
my_array.clip(0,255) # clip(min, max)
```

output:

```
array([[100, 200],
       [255, 255]], dtype=uint16)
```

Answer (score 6):

In case your question wasn't as related to the bit depth as JBernardo's answer, the more general way to do it would be something like:
(after edit, my answer is now pretty much the same as his)

```
def trunc_to( my_array, limit ):
    too_high = my_array > limit
    my_array[too_high] = limit
```

[Here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-d55e594d46b4f347c20efe1b4c65c92779f06268)'s a nice intro link for numpy bool indexing.